# Problema Android studio con Objeto Json

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un problema con mi código de Android Studio. Mi aplicación se basa en un selector de fechas en el que cuando selecciones una fecha rellenará una tabla con una consulta con la base de datos y rellenará una tabla con los resultados obtenidos. El código de mi método onCreate es el siguiente. (Editado según la respuesta de A.Cedano)

```
calendario.init(0, 0, 0, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged (DatePicker datePicker, int año, int mes, int dia){
            String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
            String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");
            int Año = calendario.getYear();
            int Mes = calendario.getMonth()+1;
            int Dia = calendario.getDayOfMonth();
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response){
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        String hora_inicio = jsonObject.getString("hora_inicio");
                        String hora_fin = jsonObject.getString("hora_fin");
                        String fecha = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                        String nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                        String apellidos = jsonObject.getString("apellidos");
                        String prestacion = jsonObject.getString("prestacion");

                        int[] comprobarFecha = separarFecha(fecha);
                        String [] arrayRespuesta = {hora_inicio, hora_fin, fecha, nombre, apellidos, prestacion};
                        if (comprobarFecha[0] == calendario.getYear() && comprobarFecha[1] == calendario.getMonth() && comprobarFecha[2] == calendario.getDayOfMonth()){
                                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                                TablaPacientes tabla = new TablaPacientes(Usuario.this, tablePaciente);
                                cargarTabla(tabla, arrayRespuesta);
                            } else {
                                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                t.show();
                            }

                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Excepción en el JSON "+e.getMessage())
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create().show();
                    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create().show();
                    }
                }
            };
            String fecha = Año+"-"+Mes+"-"+Dia;
            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, password, fecha, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Usuario.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
```

El error que me da cuando se abre esta actividad es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de porqué puede ser? Este código está probado en otra actividad y funciona, pero es la primera vez que intento meterlo dentro de un onDateChanged

Este es el resultado de mi json para usuario DONATE, clave DONATE y fecha 
"2017-10-26":

```
{
    "success": true,
    "hora_inicio": "14:00",
    "hora_fin": "14:15",
    "fecha": "2017-10-26",
    "nombre": "JUAN MANUEL",
    "apellidos": "LLORENTE RODRIGO",
    "prestacion": "REVISION OFTALMOLOGICA"
}
```

Y este es el código php de mi aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna posible solución, por favor? En el json claramente se ve que hora_inicio si que da una respuesta, pero sin embargo no parece recogerla. ¿Por qué podría ser?

Comment: podrías poner tu json? Por el error que muestra parece que intentas tratar un JSonArray como si fuese un JSonObject

Comment: Como dice Pablo, te esta devolviendo un Array y lo estas intentando parsear a un objeto simple.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que ponga una captura de lo que me devuelve el json? Porque la definición del json está en el código, dentro del onResponse

Comment: Sin embargo este mismo código le tengo en otra actividad de la misma aplicación y no me da fallos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el JSON te lo devuelve tal como lo tienes en la pregunta, estamos ante un `JSONObject`, no ante un `JSONArray`.

Entonces:

1. Deberías crear un `JSONObject` a partir de `response` y no un `JSONArray`.
2. No necesitarás el `for` si es un solo objeto JSON. Si son varios usarás el for, pero contando los valores del `JSONObject`, no del `JSONArray`.
3. En el JSON que muestras los valores no están organizados como tú intentas leerlos. Por ejemplo el nombre, no viene en una clave llamada `nombre` sino que la clave del nombre se llama `4`. Significa que esto no funcionará: `String nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");` para el nombre. En cambio esto sí: `String nombre = jsonObject.getString("4");`. Lo mismo pasa con los demás valores. Y ademas, `hora_inicio` y demás familiares no vienen en un array... no sé por qué intentas leerlos así:

   ```
                       arrayRespuesta[0] = hora_inicio;
                       arrayRespuesta[1] = hora_fin;
                       arrayRespuesta[2] = fecha;
                       arrayRespuesta[3] = nombre;
                       arrayRespuesta[4] = apellidos;
                       arrayRespuesta[5] = prestacion;
   ```

cuando esos valores vienen como claves planas en el JSON.

Es evidente que la construcción de tu JSON no se está haciendo de la forma adecuada.

De todos modos, un código corregido (para el JSON como lo tienes ahora) sería:

```
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    //String [] arrayRespuesta = new String [results.length()];

                        String hora_inicio = jsonObject.getString("1");
                        String hora_fin = jsonObject.getString("2");
                        String fecha = jsonObject.getString("3");
                        String nombre = jsonObject.getString("4");
                        String apellidos = jsonObject.getString("5");
                        String prestacion = jsonObject.getString("6");


                    //no hay aquí } de cierre del for
```

El supuesto valor de `arrayRespuesta[2]` en realidad se obtendría así:

```
                        String fechaArray = jsonObject.getString("fecha");



                    int[] comprobarFecha = separarFecha(fechaArray);

                    //... resto del código
```

Haciendo esos cambios el código funcionará si no hay otros errores. Pero no es  lo deseable. Creo que deberías revisar el JSON en el origen para que se construya con nombres de clave descriptivos y no con números.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he editado mi pregunta con tus correcciones, que me han ayudado a darme cuenta de algunos errores que tenía en mi código, a pesar de que me sigue fallando el programa.

Comment: Vale, ya lo he solucionado. Muchas gracias